# How to get and use the the number of days since the last comment?

Tags: comments

How would I achieve this condition ...

```
    if lastest comment is < 7 days old 
        echo 'New Comment';
    else ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest comment use [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).
`get_comment_date` returns the date of a comment in any format for PHP's [`date()`](http://www.php.net/date).

Now it is easy. Let's put the logic into a function to keep the global namespace clean:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of days since the latest comment.
 *
 * @return int
 */
function get_days_since_last_comment( $post_id = 0 )
{
    $args = array (
            'number' => 1,
            'status' => 'approve'
        );
    0 !== $post_id and $args['post_id'] = (int) $post_id;
    // Array of comment objects.
    $latest_comment = get_comments( $args );

    // No comments found.
    if ( ! $latest_comment )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    $comment_unix = get_comment_date( 'U', $latest_comment[0]->comment_ID );
    return round( ( time() - $comment_unix ) / 86400 );
}
```

Add the function to your plugin or to your theme's `functions.php`.

To display a special message:

```
if ( get_days_since_last_comment() > 7 )
{
    print 'Looks like everything has been said.';
}
```

To get the days for a specific post (here ID `123`) :

```
if ( get_days_since_last_comment( 123 ) > 7 )
{
    print 'Looks like everything has been said.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that speedy reply @toscho. Will the function work in the loop (index)?

Comment: When a global `post` object exists it will work. You may alter the function to accept a post ID as a parameter to pass it to `get_comments()`.

Comment: Thanks @tosho. If anyone can example "to accept a post ID as a parameter to pass it to get_comments()" I'm all ears.

Comment: See my update. :)